# Changed environment Blazor frontend no longer available

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I would like to use the lauchSettings to use another environment. I have tried with an individual environment as well as stage and release. I always have the same behavior except with Debug.

As soon as I adjust the environment via the LaunchSettings, the web page can no longer be loaded (i get a 404 message). Interestingly, the Swagger subpage is hosted correctly and works on all variants.

If it relevant, i used Blazor WASM.

launchsettings

```
     "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44344/Swagger/index.html",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
    },
    "IIS Express (Stage)": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44344/Swagger/index.html",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Stage"
      },
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
    },
```

StartUp Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (!env.IsProduction())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. 
                // You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this setting

```
 {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "add here your local host url ... ",
      "sslPort": add here you port number
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Development": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "add your localhost url"
    },
    "Staging": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "add your staging url"
    },
    "Production": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "add your production url"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it out. The page loading but it hangs. I get 3 errors in the Console
`"failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"` for `blazor.webassembly.js:1` and `jsExample.js:1`
and `"Websocket connection to 'wss://localhost:59078/[projectname]' failed"` on `aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:234`

Comment: Can you check the connectionString?

Comment: I dont know witch connectionString do you mean? from the files? i don't see them in network tab. 
I currently believe that the complete client is not delivered to IIS Express. I am using blazor wasm .net core hosted.